# How to swap nodes between two Doubly Linked List completely

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Hey everyone I am trying to swap two nodes between two Doubly Linked Lists completely (value and address too). Only the Nodes that are at the same positions can be swapped between i.e a Node at position 2 can only be swapped by the Node in position 2 in the other LinkedList. Consider the following example of 2 LinkedLists:

```
815 102 162 524 
622 101 830 754
```

Let's say we want to swap the third elements which would be 162 and 830. After swapping the LinkedLists becomes:

```
815 102 830 524 
622 101 162 754
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't swap for the previous elements.

```
void swapNodes(Node* firstListNode, Node* secondListNode)
{
    Node* FirstNodeNext = firstListNode->next;
    Node* FirstNodePrev = firstListNode->previous;
    Node* SecondNodeNext = secondListNode->next;
    Node* SecondNodePrev = secondListNode->previous;
    
    //if the nodes are heads
    if (firstListNode->previous == NULL && secondListNode->previous == NULL)
    {   
        firstListNode->next = SecondNodeNext;
        secondListNode->next = FirstNodeNext;
    }
    // if the nodes are tails
    else if(firstListNode->next == NULL && secondListNode->next == NULL)
    {
        firstListNode->previous = SecondNodePrev;
        secondListNode->previous = FirstNodePrev;
    }
    else
    {
        firstListNode->next = SecondNodeNext;
        firstListNode->previous = SecondNodePrev;

        secondListNode->next = FirstNodeNext;
        secondListNode->previous = FirstNodePrev;
     }
}
```

How can I accomplish this task?

The else if doesn't swap the previous elements, for example if we pass the value 524, and 754 to the function it should be the tail and execute the else if statement as it has no next nodes.

After the swapping it should be:

```
815 102 162 754
622 101 830 524
```

The code doesn't swap the previous nodes.

Comment: You are swapping the pointers contained in `firstListNode` and `secondListNode`,  but you are not correcting the nodes that point to them.

Comment: The easiest way to solve most linked list problems is to visualize the problem by drawing pictures. If you draw the process step-by-step you'll see if you're dropping links you need later or forgetting to make links. Base the code on the drawings, and when debugging follow the code exactly and try to draw the same pictures. If you can't you'll usually know exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: You do not have to swap the entire list, you just have to redirect, where the nodes are pointing to.

Comment: Why are you swapping the two lists? I thought you wanted to swap just the two nodes.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by *"it doesn't swap for the previous elements"*? Maybe give an example with input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Please provide the code with which you create the two example lists and make the call to this function. I do wonder why this function is called with 2 node pointers, and not an *index*, and the `lists` object.

Comment: I edited for explanation for not swapping the previous elements. I will try to visualize and recode the problem. As far as list code was concerned I removed it for being irrelevant. The main problem is the nodes doesn't point to the correct previous node pointer.

Comment: I repeat: Please provide the code with which you create the two example lists and make the call to this function. BTW, the "list code" *is* relevant: when the head-nodes need to swap, you'll have to indicate that the list references are to be swapped. In other cases they stay as they are.

Comment: @waasss *"The main problem is the nodes doesn't point to the correct previous node pointer."* -- This looks like something that can be refined with a bit of debugging. Find the line that is supposed to make one of the nodes "point to the correct previous node pointer". Use a debugger (or diagnostics to `std::cerr`) to confirm that the line is being executed and to verify that the values of your variables are what you expect at that point. What is causing this line to not function as intended?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are losing the references for swapping in other linkedlist, below is the working code snippet for the same in java. Please note, i'm assuming here that both of the linkedlist is of same length.

```
public class Application {

    static class Node{
        private int value;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void print(){
            for(Node node=this; node!=null; node = node.next){
                System.out.print(node.value + "->");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node head1 = new Node(815);
        addNodeAtLast(head1, 102);
        addNodeAtLast(head1, 162);
        addNodeAtLast(head1, 524);
        head1.print();

        Node head2 = new Node(622);
        addNodeAtLast(head2, 101);
        addNodeAtLast(head2, 830);
        addNodeAtLast(head2, 754);
        head2.print();

        swapAtIndex(head1, head2, 3);
        head1.print();
        head2.print();
    }

    private static void swapAtIndex(Node head1, Node head2, int index){
        System.out.println("Swaping node at index : "+index);
        if(index == 0){
            Node tmp = head1.next;
            head1.next= head2.next;
            head2.next = tmp;
            return;
        }
        Node linkedList1Ref = head1,  linkedList2Ref = head2;
        for(int i=0; i!=index; ++i, linkedList1Ref = linkedList1Ref.next, linkedList2Ref=linkedList2Ref.next);

        Node temp2Prev = linkedList2Ref.prev;
        Node temp2Nxt = linkedList2Ref.next;

        linkedList1Ref.prev.next = linkedList2Ref; // LinkedList 1 swap
        linkedList2Ref.prev = linkedList1Ref.prev; // LinkedList 1 swap
        if(linkedList2Ref.next != null && linkedList1Ref.next != null) {
            linkedList2Ref.next = linkedList1Ref.next; // LinkedList 1 swap
            linkedList1Ref.next.prev = linkedList2Ref; // LinkedList 1 swap
        }

        temp2Prev.next = linkedList1Ref;
        linkedList1Ref.prev = temp2Prev;
        if(linkedList1Ref.next != null && temp2Nxt != null) {
            linkedList1Ref.next = temp2Nxt;
            temp2Nxt.prev = linkedList1Ref;
        }
    }

    private static void addNodeAtLast(Node head, int value){
        Node temp = new Node(value);
        Node prev = null;
        for(prev=head; prev.next != null; prev=prev.next);
        temp.prev = prev;
        prev.next = temp;
    }
}
```